# How to convert an array to Collection in backbone

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have an array defined as:

```
this.noOfHouseHold = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];
```

I'm trying to convert it to a Backbone Collection as:

```
var adultListCollection = new Backbone.Collection(this.noOfHouseHold);
```

It gives me the list but for 2 digit numbers, it shows something like this:

```
attributes: Object
0: "1"
1: "1"
```

I'm not able to understand as to what is wrong here or is it the wrong way I'm converting my array to collections. Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Backbone collection expects a list of models/hashes of attributes that can be converted to a model but you have a plain array.

You will have to transform your array to a list of hashes. Assuming your values are the `id`s of your models :

```
var lst = _.map(this.noOfHouseHold, function(val) {
    return {id: val};
});
var adultListCollection = new Backbone.Collection(lst);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Collection` expects a list of models or objects (because they can be converted to `Backbone.Model`). In order to persist the array you have to convert those primitives into objects. Use `Backbone.Collection.parse` and `_.map` to turn your array of primitives into an array of objects:

```
var AdultListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function (noOfHouseHold) {
    var res = _.map(noOfHouseHold, function (n) {
        return {id: n};
    });
    return res;
  }
});
```

Now you can instantiate your Collection with an array:

```
var adultListCollection = new AdultListCollection(this.noOfHouseHold, {parse: true});
```

**Example:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2JR8/33/)